# Arithmetic operation doesn't work with variable

Tags: c

I created this variable `float avg_perc` and performed some arithmetic operation to find average percentage. The output is unexpected i.e. 0 for any value of marks1, mark2, marks3.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int marks1, marks2, marks3;
    printf("Enter your marks in all 3 subjects : ");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &marks1, &marks2, &marks3);
    float avg_perc = ((marks1+marks2+marks3)/300)*100;    //problem part
    printf("%f \n", avg_perc);
    if(avg_perc>=40 &&marks1>=33 && marks2>=33 && marks3>=33){
        printf("Pass.");
    }
    else{
        printf("Fail.");
    }
     return 0;

}
```

Comment: As the variables are in integer and you are performing an integer operation the output is 0. Try converting the expression and check ' float avg_perc = ((marks1+marks2+marks3)/300.0)*100; '. Either typecast the expression that is adding the marks or make the change as shown above to get the correct result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't really matter that you have `float avg_perc = ...` for storing the result, because that type does not affect the type used for the calculations.

In C, every operand and integer constant in an expression has a type. And depending on the types of the operands, each operation is carried out on a specific type which then also becomes the resulting type of the (sub) expression.

In this case the types are as indicated by the comment below:

```
    float avg_perc = ((marks1 + marks2 + marks3) / 300) * 100;
//        float        int    + int    + int     / int  * int
```

*Operator precedence* determines which operands that belong to which operator. In this case the `()` parenthesis has the highest precedence, then `*` and `/`, then `+` and finally `=`.

The subexpression `(marks1 + marks2 + marks3)` will get all calculations carried out on `int` type since all involved operands of + are `int`. Then the result of that will form a new expression "result / 300" where `300` is `int`. Again, calculation is carried out on `int`. And then finally the same thing with `* 100`.

When all the above calculations have been carried out on `int`, then the assignment happens last of all, since `=` has the lowest precedence. During assignment, there is a special conversion rule stating that the value of the right operand is is converted to the type of the left operand. So this conversion of the result to `float` happens last, when all of the other calculations have already been carried out on `int`.

Comment: Best answer ever for one of the most duplicate questions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the divisor a type of `double` by appending `.0` into it to avoid the integer division and this was exactly the reason you were having this strange issue.

Change:

```
(marks1 + marks2 + marks3) / 300
```

into:

```
(marks1 + marks2 + marks3) / 300.0
```

Note that if you put a floating point prefix, for instance `300.0f` then you'll see a miscalculation. For example, you get `30.000002` after inputting `30 30 30` in the program.

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
  ((marks1+marks2+marks3)/300)*100;
```

is integer arithmetic. You need to ensure at least one of the participating arguments are floating point (or casted to a float or double) in order to ensure floating point arithmetic. Something like

```
(((float)marks1+marks2+marks3)/300)*100;
```